# Can't use custom emoji in title of embed

Tags: discord.js

Using my custom emoji in the description of an embed looks fine but on the title it just shows it in `<:emojiName:emojiID>` format. Here's a screenshot of it:

[image: Example]

Comment: That's normal. Unfortunately emoji's are not parsed in title's or footers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it **is** possible to use custom emojis in embed titles, but I was using `.setAuthor()` instead of `.setTitle()`, thats why it wasn't working out.

Answer (score 2):

[Discord's REST based API](https://discord.com/developers/docs/intro) simply does not parse [emoji objects](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/emoji#emoji-object) in the embeds's footer and author section, only title, fields and description may contain emojis. However you can always use `utf8` based emojis !